# rewrite rule php correct page

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

i have in a file rewrite.php following rules

```
$rewrites = array(
'#^/searchresults.html$#' => '/info/searchresults'

);

$reverseRewrites = array (
'#^/info/searchresults$#' => '/searchresults.html'

);
```

this work and give me correct page searchresults.html
but  with google custom search
i have error page non found because
 format of searchresults page is:

```
http://site.com/searchresults.html?cx=partner-pub-***********&cof=FORID%3A10&ie=UTF-8&q=***&sa=Search&siteurl=site.com%2F
```

so can you help me to insert correct rewrite rule for this specific url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what API you are using for these rewrites, but the problem looks to be that the regex ends after `.html` and so it is not matching your query string. Something like this might help:

```
$rewrites = array(
'#^/searchresults.html(|\?.*)$#' => '/info/searchresults$1'

);

$reverseRewrites = array (
'#^/info/searchresults(|\?.*)$#' => '/searchresults.html$1'

);
```

Comment: correct i have inserted only first $rewrites = array(
'#^/searchresults.html(|\?.*)$#' => '/info/searchresults$1'

);
and second leave intact thanks now working